# Django Views Incrementing Variables

Tags: python, django, operators, increment

When I increment one of my variables, it only goes up to 2 instead of 3. The default value is 1. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

```
def unanswered(request, template ='unanswered.html'):
    phone_number = Pool.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    pool = Pool.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    pool_list = Pool.objects.all()
    number_attempts = Pool.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).count()


    # unanswer number action

        if pool_list:
            if number_attempts > 3:
                return number_attempts

            else:
                x = number_attempts
                x += 1 
                print x 'returns 2'
                store = Pool(id=phone_number.id,
                             phone_number = phone_number.phone_number,
                             un_answered=x, answered=0)
                store.save()

    payload = {'pool':pool,}

    return render_to_response(template, payload, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: From your question I can't guess what is the value of `number_attempts` in `else` block. If it's `1` then `x +=1` should indeed return `2`. :-)

Comment: the number_attempts, it counts the number of the exact phone_number it gets. So default it's 1, then I want to keep increment it til it reaches 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any `for loop` or `while loop` in your code, so if initial `number_attempts` is 1, it will incremented to 2 and complete the flow.

I see you want to store attempts in the DB, but the way you are doing is not correct. You are passing `id=phone_number.id` to `Store(...)`, which will try to update existing record if exists with given `id`. So `Pool.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).count()` always returns 1.

You may want to change it to

```
store = Pool(phone_number = phone_number.phone_number,
             un_answered=x, answered=0)
```

So for the next request, `Pool.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).count()` will give you 2.

---

Update after the comment:

> All I want is to update the un_answered field from 1,2,3.

In that case, don't use `.count()` to get number of failed attempts use the field from object that has that counter.

So instead of

```
number_attempts = Pool.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).count()
```

you can do this

```
try:
    store = Pool.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
    number_attempts = store.un_answered

# FIX : the original code used a bare except clause.
# Bare except clauses are EVIL. DONT use bare except clauses. NEVER.
# Or thou shall burn in the flames of hell for your eternal death....

except Pool.DoesNotExist:
    store = Pool(phone_number = phone_number.phone_number,
                 un_answered=1, answered=0)
    store.save()
    number_attempts = 1

...
if pool_list:
        if number_attempts > 3:
            return number_attempts

        else:
            x = number_attempts
            x += 1 
            print x 'returns 2'
            store.un_answered = x
            store.save()
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way I want it. It's creating the same phone number over and over again. All I want is to update the un_answered field from 1,2,3. That's why I added the ID so it just updates the record, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @Infinixd, in that case check the updated answer. BTW, specifying `id` to create object is generally not good idea.

Comment: @Rohan : PLEASE do NOT post code snippets with a bare `except` clause. Bare `except` clauses are EVIL. NEVER assume you know which exception was raised. In the above case (fixed), you want to catch `Pool.DoesNotExist` and nothing else.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I agree, but assume that much from the OP. Code posted here is a sample to solve issues.

Comment: Thank you for all your input guys. This really helped me. I just made a slight change on "if number_attempts > 3" to ">=" and I had to remove return number_attempts, it gives me an error "'long' object has no attribute 'status_code'". Have you guys seen that error?

Comment: @Infinixd, that is because django view should return `HTTPResponse` type variable, which `number_attempts` is not.

Comment: Thanks Rohan I'll keep that noted. I'm still very new to Django. Trying to expand my knowledge by trying out new projects.